# How to use Valo fonts in custom theme

Tags: fonts, themes, vaadin

The new [Valo theme](https://vaadin.com/valo) in Vaadin 7.3 and later comes bundled with some fonts:

- [Lato](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato)
- [Lora](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lora)
- [Open Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans)
- [Roboto](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto)
- [Source Sans Pro](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro)

I'm struggling with adding these Valo fonts into my custom theme.
This is what I have but it doesn't seem to work.

styles.scss

```
$v-font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif, 'Open Sans';

@import "../valo/valo";

.myTheme {

@include valo;

@import "myRules"; 

}
```

This is what I get in the console:

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://name/name/VAADIN/themes/myTheme/Lato-regular-webfont.woff

It should point to http://name/name/VAADIN/themes/valo/Lato-regular-webfont.woff

I guess I forgot about something but I've searched and it's not mentioned in the Book of Vaadin.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is resolved, I was missing this:

```
$v-relative-paths: false;
```

source: http://vaadin.com/download/book-of-vaadin/current-br/html/themes.valo.html

> Theme Compilation and Optimization
>
> $v-relative-paths (default: false) This flags specifies whether
>   relative URL paths are relative to the currently parsed SCSS file or
>   to the compilation root file, so that paths are correct for different
>   resources. Vaadin theme compiler parses URL paths differently from the
>   regular Sass compiler (Vaadin modifies relative URL paths). Use false
>   for Ruby compiler and true for Vaadin compiler.